# Regular expression in javascript?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, regex

I want to know how to write the regular expression in javascript. Please help me. Give a simple example with details. I mean the source code (i am using asp.net and c# language).

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tons of examples online for using JavaScript's RegExp object. Start with [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

Here is a simple example of creating a RegExp and then using it to determine whether there is at least one occurrence of the word "dog" in the passed string.

```
var myString = "I wish all dogs were brown.";
var myRegExp = new RegExp("dog");
var containsDog = myRegExp.test(myString);
```

In this example, containsDog would be 'true'.

Comment: Unless you are building a regex expression by concatenating strings, go with the short syntax

var myRegExp = /dog/  // Equivalent to new RegExp("dog")

and if you want to ignore case do like so
var myRegExp = /dog/i  // Equivalent to new RegExp("dog", "i")

and if you want to add the global parameter

var myRegExp = /dog/g  // Equivalent to new RegExp("dog", "g")

You can also use both
var myRegExp = /dog/ig  // Equivalent to new RegExp("dog", "ig")

Answer (score 1):

You may want to refer concise article on : www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

First you need to understand the concept of regular expression. Once you know what regex is, writing them in any language is not difficult.

Comment: As for me, regex is always difficult :)

Answer (score 1):

You can read these

[Regular Expressions](http://www.learn-javascript-tutorial.com/RegularExpressions.cfm)

[Regular Expressions patterns](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml)

[String and Regular Expression methods](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/re3.shtml)

If you are interested in buying a regex book then this one is good

[Regular Expressions Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520694)

Answer (score 1):

I think the following articles from Mozilla Dev Center are a very good introduction:

- [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [Working with Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Regular_Expressions).
- [Examples of Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Regular_Expressions/Examples_of_Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 0):

You can write a *regular expression literal* enclosed in slashes like this:

```
var re = /\w+/;
```

That matches something that contains one or more word characters.

You can also create a regular expression from a string:

```
var re = new RegExp("\\w+");
```

Notice that since that's a string literal, I have to double the backslash to *escape* its special meaning for strings.

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
var myString = "I wish all dogs were brown.";
if (myString.match(/dog/i))
{
    //do something
}
```